# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bool' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am getting the following runtime error when running my code. I did have everything working, but started getting this error and ran an update on my npm. So I am not sure where the error is happening.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bool' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:68041)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:67829)
    at bundle.js:67849
    at bundle.js:67852
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (bundle.js:67802)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (bundle.js:67809)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (bundle.js:37173)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (bundle.js:35709)
```

Here is my webapck config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./public/bis/js/'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-router-dom": "latest",
    "@types/globalize": "0.0.31",
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.2",
    "globalize": "^1.3.0",
    "jquery": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.11.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react-bootstrap-date-picker": "^5.1.0",
    "react-drawer": "^1.2.5",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-moment": "^0.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-select": "^1.2.1",
    "react-widgets": "^4.1.2",
    "react-widgets-globalize": "^4.0.5",
    "react-widgets-moment": "^4.0.5",
    "reactstrap": "^5.0.0-alpha.4",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.2.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.2.2",
    "jest": "^21.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^11.5.1",
    "mocha": "^4.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "nodemon": "~1.3.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.1.1",
    "redux-test-utils": "^0.2.2",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "request-promise-core": "^1.1.1",
    "sinon": "^4.1.3"
  }
```

The code that surrounds 68041 has to do with react-drawer

Any thoughts, online it appears that react-bootstrap often has this error, but I updated that to the latest release. Did not fix the error.The error states webpackUniversalModuleDefinition is the problem, but I did not find anything on Google about that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally `npm update` is a bad idea because it attempts to update everything and that can cause issues with dependencies being upgraded to a non backwards compatible version. You should always target specific packages when using `npm update`: `npm update react react-dom`. What does the code at bundle.js line 68041 look like?

Comment: I didn't do npm update. Did npm install, and only changed react, react-dom, react-bootstrap, and react-router-dom to latest. I will do your update specific packages from now on. I have put the code at 68041 up in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found the answer, it does not work with [react-drawer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-drawer). I added that as a new component. I took that out and now compiles and runs.